# Selenium IDE to Java

Tags: java, selenium, junit, automation, selenium-webdriver

I am fairly new to Selenium Automation Testing and am experiencing something that I do not see in videos and tutorials.

I used Selenium IDE to record a test of: 
navigating through a website 
logging in
edit profile information
submit changes
verify changes

It works fine when I replay it in Firefox. My issue is when I export it to Java - Junit Webdriver and run the test via Eclipse it takes a very long time to go through the steps and thus causing failure or just fails overall.

I tried to even do it by hand step by step and that also seems to work but the part that takes the longest is to input the user login information (Username & Password).

**Is there something this newbie is not aware of? 
Should the exported IDE work "Out of the box" when it is run via Eclipse Junit?**

```
package Profile;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.junit.*;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class ProfileChangeTestCase {
  private WebDriver driver;
  private String baseUrl;
  private StringBuffer verificationErrors = new StringBuffer();


  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    baseUrl = "http://gaming.twlstaging.com/";
  }

  @Test
  public void testOpen() throws Exception {
    driver.get(baseUrl);
    //Click LogIn
    driver.findElement(By.className("logged-out")).click();
    //Enter User name
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login']")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login']")).sendKeys("Demo");
    //Enter Password
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login_password']")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='login_password']")).sendKeys("Blam!");
    //Click LogIn Button
    driver.findElement(By.className("login-button")).click();
    //Security Alert - Selecting continue
    Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
    alert.accept();
    //Buffer for page to load
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Verify user name login by echo name to console
    String text = driver.findElement(By.className("user-name")).getText();
    System.out.println("Username is :" + text);
    //Buffer for contents to load
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //Click on Edit Profile
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='user-navigation']/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
    //Change description in profile
    driver.findElement(By.name("interests")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("interests")).sendKeys("This was done in Selenium Eclipse");
    //Update Profile
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type=\"submit\"]")).click();


  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    String verificationErrorString = verificationErrors.toString();
    if (!"".equals(verificationErrorString)) {
      fail(verificationErrorString);
    }
  }
  private boolean isAlertPresent() {
        try {
          driver.switchTo().alert();
          return true;
        } catch (NoAlertPresentException e) {
          return false;
        }
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you also try [Selenium Builder](http://sebuilder.github.io/se-builder/) and see if that works better for you.